I need to understand Artificers
I'm a DM who has recently moved to 3.5e and have some questions about the artificer class from Eberron Campaign Setting.
My future artificer player knows that artificers have good access to healing through infusions, and the internet backs up that idea (Greater Healing Infusion, MIC 29 I think), but I can't find where it's explained that Artificers would be able to use armor properties as infusions. I see armor enhancement but all I see is

Armor Enhancement, LesserM*: Armor or shield gains special ability with +1 bonus market price modifier.

That would allow a player to select one of the special abilities? Is there a restriction to this, or any other limits? I understood the wording as "armor is +1" basically.
A lot of the discourse online seems to assume that Artificers can use a lot more infusions than the ones available in the Eberron Campaign Setting, but I can't for the life of me find the references to read up on.
Can someone give me pointers so I can do my work and connect the dots? I don't need things fed to me (I don't mind them either), but just pointing me at which books explain things about the artificer would be awesome, so as to save me having to read a million books 'just in case'.

I’m not entirely sure what the issue here is, but you’re not allowed to damage questions, even your own. The additional context from your comments is important to understanding your full question, and therefore will remain in your question. Feel free to edit the actual text if you like, but you cannot just remove it—edits may only be performed to improve questions, not worsen them.

There seems to be some confusion about artificers as healers: they have no innate ability to heal anyone but constructs. The way they heal people is by producing healing items, either permanent items with their crafting ability, or temporary ones with their infusions. For example, the linked discussion references using the armor enhancement infusion to put the greater healing special property on an armor—that heals 3d8+15 (average 28½) hp for 50 gp (1.8 gp per hp healed). This is better than a wand of cure light wounds (2.7 gp per hp healed), and almost as good as a wand of lesser vigor (1.4 gp per hp healed), but without the upfront cost (750 gp for a 50-charge wand), the need to have the wand in-hand, or the minute+ that lesser vigor takes to actually heal that much. (And, of course, the artificer should be able to zap either wand as well as anybody, and can also easily craft them once Craft Wand is gained at 6th level.)
The infusions that improve armor are pretty much just what you see in Eberron Campaign Setting, primarily the armor enhancement line for special properties and the magic vestment line for straight AC bonuses. The ablative armor infusion from Magic of Eberron exists, but it’s pretty poor.
The only books that include artificer infusions are

Eberron Campaign Setting—the base list, including 32 new infusions and assigning several Player’s Handbook spells to the artificer as infusions
Magic of Eberron—12 new infusions
Faiths of Eberron—2 new infusions (lesser construct essence, mass lesser construct essence)
Explorer’s Handbook—1 new infusion (invoke elemental)
Dragonmarked—6 new infusions
The Forge of War—2 new infusions (knight unburdened, swift ready)
Races of Eberron—15 new infusions

A complete list of all of the infusions can be found here.
The best resource on most of the artificer class is probably Disregard Money, Acquire Buff Spells: Artificers without the Artifice. Though it doesn’t cover any of the crafting that an artificer can do, it covers everything else very thoroughly. As for the crafting, that mostly just involves knowing what to craft, which usually means looking through item lists rather than anything specific to the artificer class. The artificer-specific things to keep aware of are the need to keep Use Magic Device up—the skill checks required to emulate spells for crafting are fairly high—and the fact that the artificer’s craft homunculus ability can help with crafting by creating a dedicated wright homunculus (Eberron Campaign Setting). Oh, and knowing what spells to put into wands and so on, which an artificer may want to do more than most spellcasters would.

A lot of the discussion around healing and artificer's I've read comes from posts like this:
https://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=2710.0
And there IS a healing and greater healing PROPERTY for armor in the MIC (p. 12), which people in posts such as the one above suggest can be infused through artificer infusions, somehow at a much lower cost than indicated in the manual.
That is basically what I'm looking an answer to

@DiegoElias Ah! You should add that to your question—I can explain what’s going on there. They’re mostly discussing the artificer’s ability to create items that heal, either permanently with their crafting, or temporarily with their infusions. That’s what “Greater Healing armor infusion” is: using the armor enhancement infusion to temporarily give an armor the greater healing special property, which heals the wearer. I agree with the author that an artificer can make a lot of healing available to the party through their crafting and infusions, but I think they could be clearer.

fair enough! Meaning:
Armor Enhancement, LesserM*: Armor or shield
gains special ability with +1 bonus market price
modifier.
That would allow a player to select one of the special abilities? Is there a restriction to this, or any other limits?
I understood the wording as "armor is +1" basically, but I guess the right interpretation would be "you can select any special ability from the MIC, with a +1 mod to price", correct?

@DiegoElias That’s the short description—you’ll want to check the full description for more details. There, you see “You can choose any special ability whose market price is equivalent to a +1 bonus or up to 5,000 gp.” So yes, you can choose any special ability (from Magic Item Compendium or anywhere else) within those limits. But you could not, for example, choose to add animated to a shield, because its cost is equivalent to +2. Likewise, the greater healing property (MIC pg. 12) is 24,000 gp. Those require armor enhancement (+3 or 35,000 gp).

good stuff brother. Where's the full description at though? The Eberron handbook only has the one I pasted, but I do absolutely get the gist of it and it all makes a lot more sense now!

@DiegoElias Eberron Campaign Setting, pg. 109.

oh well, LMAO I guess. Thanks for the help dude, I'll make sure to read up on this over the week and figure things out then, thanks again!

For armor, you can find the Armor Enhancement infusions (Lesser, normal, and Greater) starting at the end of pg. 108 in the Eberron Campaign Setting book.
As for other resources, it is split amongst the other Eberron books:

Races of Eberron
Magic of Eberron
Eberron Explorer's Handbook

There's also a lot of bonus Eberron content in various issues of Dragon magazine between issues 315 and 408.
